# How to pass another class strings to Jlabel API

Tags: java, swing

How set text in Jlabel:

PsoMath1.java class contains method (print soliution)

```
int printSolution()
{
    // Find solution particle.
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < particles.size(); i++)
    {
        if(testProblem(i) == TARGET){
            break;
        }
    }
    // Print it.
    **System.out.println("Particle " + i + " has achieved target.");**
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX_INPUTS; j++)
    {
        if(j < MAX_INPUTS - 1){
            System.out.print(particles.get(i).data(j) + " + ");
        }else{
            System.out.print(particles.get(i).data(j) + " = " + TARGET);
        }
    } // j
    System.out.print("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Pso.java contains Jbutton:here, I want to set the text from another class.

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    psomath1 ob =new psomath1();



   String n1 = TARGETS.getText();
   TARGETT= Integer.parseInt(n1);
   ob.TARGET=TARGETT;

 String n2 = MAXINPUTS.getText();
 final int MAX_INPUTST = Integer.parseInt(n2);
 ob.MAX_INPUTS=MAX_INPUTST;

 String n3 = MAXPARTICLES.getText();
 final int MAX_PARTICLEST = Integer.parseInt(n3);
  ob.MAX_PARTICLES=MAX_PARTICLEST;
 String n4 = VMAX.getText();
 final int V_MAXT  = Integer.parseInt(n4);
 ob.V_MAX =V_MAXT;    
 String n5 = MAXEPOCHS.getText();
 final int MAX_EPOCHST = Integer.parseInt(n5);    
 ob.MAX_EPOCHS =MAX_EPOCHST;  
 String n6 = STARTRANGEMIN .getText();
 final int START_RANGE_MINT  = Integer.parseInt(n6);    
ob.START_RANGE_MIN =START_RANGE_MINT;  
String n7 = STARTRANGEMAX.getText();
 final int START_RANGE_MAXT  = Integer.parseInt(n7); 
ob.START_RANGE_MIN =START_RANGE_MINT;  

ob.PSOAlgorithm();


**PRINTIT.setText(Integer.toString(ob.printSolution()));**
return;



}
```

But the output prints:0.

How to print the last iteration value?

Comment: Turn off the caps lock, shouty.

Comment: As a side note, may be you don't know but typing in capital letter means you are yelling or shouting. So next time keep it in your mind.

Comment: not works printit.setText(Integer.toString(ob.printSolution()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your method printSolution at the end returns 0 and that's what you set label as.

```
PRINTIT.setText(Integer.toString(ob.printSolution()));
```

Comment: Cool closet his question by accepting the answer if it helped.